# Manipulations with the metric tensor

Tags: tensors

The problem is

$``\textbf{for a function $f$ of $p^2=p_{\mu}p^{\mu}$, show that}$

$$
         I_{\mu\nu}=\int d^4p\ \, p_{\mu}p_{\nu}f(p^2)
         =\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{4}\int d^4p\ \, p^2f(p^2),\tag{1}
$$
$\textbf{and}$
$$
         J_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
         =\int d^4p\ \, p_{\mu}p_{\nu}p_{\rho}p_{\sigma}f(p^2)
         =\frac{1}{24}\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\rho\sigma}
                       +\eta_{\mu\rho}\eta_{\nu\sigma}
                       +\eta_{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\nu\rho}\right)
                       \int d^4p\ \, (p^2)^2f(p^2)."\tag{2}
$$

Now, for $I_{\mu\nu}$, since $\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}=\delta^{\mu}_{\mu}=4$, we have
\begin{align*}
         I_{\mu\nu}&=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}}{4}
                       \int d^4p\ \, p_{\mu}p_{\nu}f(p^2)\\
                   &=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{4}
                       \int d^4p\ \, \eta^{\mu\nu}p_{\mu}p_{\nu}f(p^2)\\
                   &=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{4}
                       \int d^4p\ \, p^{\nu}p_{\nu}f(p^2)\\
                   &=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{4}
                       \int d^4p\ \, p^2f(p^2).
\end{align*}
However, for $J_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, using the same reasoning, I can't see why it shouldn't be that
\begin{align*}
           J_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
           &=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}}{4}
                   \frac{\eta_{\rho\sigma}\eta^{\rho\sigma}}{4}
                   \int d^4p\ \, p_{\mu}p_{\nu}p_{\rho}p_{\sigma}f(p^2)\\
           &=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\rho\sigma}}{16}
                   \int d^4p\ \, p^{\nu}p_{\nu}p^{\sigma}p_{\sigma}f(p^2)\\
           &=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\rho\sigma}}{16}
                   \int d^4p\ \, (p^2)^2f(p^2).
\end{align*}
What is it that I'm missing; i.e. how do the terms $\eta_{\mu\rho}\eta_{\nu\sigma}$ and $\eta_{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\nu\rho}$ in $(2)$ arise?

Comment: I'd advise you to be more careful with your notation. In your attempt for solving the first problem you use 

$$
I_{\mu\nu}=\frac{\eta_{\color{red}{\mu}\nu}\eta^{\color{red}{\mu}\nu}}{4}
                       \int d^4p\ \, p_{\color{red}{\mu}}p_{\nu}f(p^2)
$$

I highlighted the index $\mu$ just emphasize that you have **three** indexes on the same factor with the same symbol, this is not allowed!

Comment: Thanks for the response; apart from the bad notation, do i have the right idea - do you have any suggestions as to how I should proceed?